# Omega using wrong grid class?

Tags: theming

So, I'm using Omega (with custom subtheme), and I'm running into a strange issue. I have a logo block in header first which only displays on the front page (and has grid-3 class), and I have a menu in header second which is displayed everywhere (and has grid-9 class). The front page is fine, but on every other page the region-header-second div with the menu keeps the grid-9 class, which is kind of messing with the layout. Shouldn't this automatically be set to grid-12 when the block in header first is absent? Has anyone run across this? It sort of feels like this is just 'stuck', but clear cache, etc. hasn't

Answer (score 0):

Within your subtheme settings drill down to the specific region you have problems with and make sure the prefix and suffix settings are correct.

Comment: Shouldn't prefixes/suffixes generally just be zero (which is what they are)? Header first is three columns, header second is nine columns, and the header zone is twelve columns. Shouldn't header second automatically get set to twelve columns to fill the entire zone when header first is absent? I know this is how it's working with the content region when the sidebar is absent, and neither of those regions has (pre|suf)fixes.